# Most efficient way to input char using getchar() just like cin without new line and whitespace chars in C++

Tags: c++, newline, whitespace, getchar

My problem are white spaces and new lines (\n) on output using getchar() function on input. While using cin, white spaces and newlines are not visible on output.

Here is the implementation:

```
while (tmpChar = getchar())
{
cout << tmpChar;
}
```

and the implementation using cin:

```
while (cin >> tmpChar)
{
    cout << tmpChar;
}
```

Here is the difference on output (red squares are output):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Lyv.png

I'm looking for optimal way to remove these spaces and new lines.

Thank you for replies!

Comment: I don't understand whether you want the spaces or you don't. If you don't, why not simply use the solution that you've already identified strips spaces????

Comment: BTW your first loop is broken; terminate on `tmpChar` equalling `EOF`, not `'0'`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: of course, `tmpChar` would also have to be an `int`, which would probably not give the expected output.

Comment: @FredLarson: It had bloomin' well better be an `int`, since that's the return type of `getchar()`... however, the `cout` line does indeed suggest that it's not. I guess the OP cannot use documentation, then!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, that's what I'm saying. But then the output won't look like the input, will it? It would need a cast back to `char` on the output.

Comment: Hard to figure out this question. I'm wondering if it relates to [`std::skipws`/`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws).

Comment: @FredLarson: Yes and that's what you _must_ do when you use `getchar()`.

Comment: @FredLarson: Yes, it does. The OP is using formatted extraction in the first case and unformatted in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` will just pull the next character from `stdin`, regardless of whether it is whitespace or not. You will have to check if a character is whitespace before sending it to `stdout`. Something like:

```
while (tmpChar = getchar())
{
    if (!isspace(tmpChar))
        cout << tmpChar;
}
```

You will need to `#include <cctype>` to get the `isspace` definition.

Comment: Interesting output when `tmpChar == EOF`.  Maybe `if (!isspace(tmpChar) && tmpChar != EOF))`

Comment: It's because `tmpChar` is a `char`. _It must be an `int`_.